# BlueTooth shown in `lshw` but not activated

Tags: bluetooth

`lshw` shows:

```
          *-usb UNCLAIMED
               description: Bluetooth wireless interface
               product: HP Integrated Module
               vendor: Broadcom Corp
               physical id: 1
               bus info: usb@3:1
               version: 1.00
               capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
               configuration: speed=12Mbit
```

`lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Bluetooth 2.0 Interface [Broadcom BCM2045]
```

But `hcitool dev` gives:

```
Devices:
```

What am I missing to get BlueTooth active?

Answer (score -1):

On of these helped:

```
root@hk:~# modprobe btintel
root@hk:~# modprobe bnep
root@hk:~# modprobe bluetooth
root@hk:~# modprobe brcmfmac
root@hk:~# modprobe brcmutil
root@hk:~# modprobe realtek
root@hk:~# modprobe evdev
```

`hcitool dev` still shows nothing, but `hciconfig -a` now shows:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:27:13:6D:4C:DF  ACL MTU: 1017:8  SCO MTU: 64:8
```